# Dash: how to write callback for html.Form component

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am developing a dash app. I am creating a form using **html.Form** component.

```
html.Form(
   id="form_upload",
   name="form_upload",
   method="POST",
   action="/upload",
   encType="multipart/form-data",
   # accept="application/octet-stream",
   children=[
       dbc.Input(id="ip_name", name="ip_name", type="text"),
       dbc.Input(id="ip_upload", name="ip_upload", type="file"),
       dbc.Input(id="ip_submit", name="ip_submit", type="submit"),
   ],
),
```

But I have no clue how to write a callback for above form, so that I can access and process the form inputs(request payload) i.e. name and file contents.
I read offical document and searched alot but didnot find any demo or example.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

do you want the callback to trigger whenever an input is typed (for every letter)? If so you can trigger the callback using the 'value' parameter from the Input field. See dbc examples below:

```
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash import Input, Output, html

text_input = html.Div(
    [
        dbc.Input(id="input", placeholder="Type something...", type="text"),
        html.Br(),
        html.P(id="output"),
    ]
)


@app.callback(Output("output", "children"), [Input("input", "value")])
def output_text(value):
    return value
```

If you dont want it to trigger with every input, you should add a submit button to the form. In which case you can use the Buttons n_click parameter for the trigger:

```
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash import Input, Output, html

button = html.Div(
    [
        dbc.Button(
            "Click me", id="example-button", className="me-2", n_clicks=0
        ),
        html.Span(id="example-output", style={"verticalAlign": "middle"}),
    ]
)


@app.callback(
    Output("example-output", "children"), [Input("example-button", "n_clicks")]
)
def on_button_click(n):
    if n is None:
        return "Not clicked."
    else:
        return f"Clicked {n} times."
```

Good luck =)

Comment: Hi Kristian, Thanks. I am familiar with basic callbacks like you shared above. But I donot know about html.Form and html.Button, these both have form related options, so how to fetch and process the form-data like attached file etc in the form callback.

Comment: What's the reason you want to use the post functionality of the html form? In Dash apps you mainly use the html.Form for organization of the html code. Instead you trigger the callbacks using either Input fields or buttons as I described above. The POST and GET functionality can be used to communicate with external servers and applications (so some use cases do exist), but not for Dash callbacks as far as I know. The input fields on the other hand are pretty straight forward to use.

Comment: Hi Kristian, Indeed as you mentioned. The reason for using post functionality is for file upload. I did used dcc.Upload and it is working but I come to know that it also store the data on client side in web browser memory, as my file size is large it will affect browser and app. so I'm trying to use form functionality to handle manually.

Comment: I think you need to look outside Dash for this functionality. I don't think it has been implemented, as they are mostly focused on using the input fields, tables and buttons for callbacks.

Comment: Hi Kristian, It would have been great to have a form callback. While searching more I found [dash-uploader](https://pypi.org/project/dash-uploader/) library.